# What do I need to check and/or modify in my .NET application if I enable SQL Server 2012 partitioning feature?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, ado.net, database-partitioning

I have a .NET (v4.0) application that uses Linq2Sql to connect to a MS Sql Server 2012 Enterprise Edition database.

I am now thinking of enabling the partitioning feature for a specific table in my DB that is storing millions of rows, the partitioning rule could be a timestamp or an integer value representing the "importance" of the row itself.

Could someone give me an advice on the major issues that can occur when enabling this feature?

I mean, do I have to pay attention to any specific programming block that could give issues during application execution?

I also make use of:

- stored procedures (only T-SQL, no CLR)
- user-defined functions with recursive CTE's (on that specific table).
- SqlBulkCopy from .NET code (I am not using the command-line tool)
- Microsoft Ditributed Transaction Coordinator (MSDTC) for TransactionScope

Comment: The most major issue is that queries not written for partitioning tend to query multiple partitions. Your queries will become slower. Plans become worse.

Comment: Thanks @usr, all my queries have been modified in order to include the field that I am using for partitioning. My concern is about possible errors or different behavior, not speed. Speed will be accurately tested.